# Apply conditional style in Jaspersoft iReport based on value?

Tags: jasper-reports

I tried to apply conditional style into my iReport based on value. The below is partial of code. It works, but only forecolor.  just want to know how to get it work on fontsize also.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Eligibility Report" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" whenResourceMissingType="Empty" uuid="519852db-b571-4ddd-86c0-9e09e13fb7e9">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>

    <style name="HBA1C">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{HBA1C}.equals("Yes")]]></conditionExpression>
            <style forecolor="#000000"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{HBA1C}.equals("No")]]></conditionExpression>
            <style forecolor="#FF0000" backcolor="#FF0000" fontSize="40"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 2):

the default setting for background might be set to transparent. You need to add the property `mode="Opaque"`. Make sure that the elements that are going to use this style do not overwrite this setting.

```
<style forecolor="#FF0000" backcolor="#FF0000" mode="Opaque" fontSize="40"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. adding mode="Opaque" is very important to get forecolor and backcolor.  but still can not get fontsize working. Any ideas?

Comment: if the font size does not apply it is very likely that it is set on the element itself too. If you use Jaspersoft Studio Inheritance View you can see which level (style reference, style, element) sets a certain property. Inspect the element which should have the font size, in the property panel you can right click on font size to reset the default value.

Answer (score -1):

if only are two styles,  you could create two fields with different styles and use "print when expression"

Comment: this isn't a good recommendation. It adds unnecessary complexity; decreases maintainability of the report, makes it complicated as soon as you have to maintain more than one condition. Conditional styles are the way to go if you want to implement context dependent formatting.